# Laravel CORS subdomain session

Tags: php, ajax, session, laravel

I'm having problems with Auth::check() in subdomain via ajax requests..
Scenario:
2 subdomains

```
www.testing.dev
api.testing.dev
```

Single login/session between those two..
in the laravel config/session.php i have set `'domain' => ".testing.dev"`, and everything is working fine, i'm able to login in one page and continue to be logged in the other page also!

But when i use ajax there is a problem..
scenario: being in the `api.testing.dev`, i perform with firebug, js, whatever

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.testing.dev/who',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false
});
```

the `api.stesting.dev/who` returns:

```
public function getWho(){
    return var_dump( Auth::user() );
}
```

The response is the information of my account! all correct..

if from the `www.testing.dev` i perform the same ajax query, i get Auth::check() returning null. Though i get normal response, so no problem with cross domain setup.. here are my headers in in the route for the `api.testing.dev`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

The website is running in localhost with wamp.

Edit: with the default session driver `'driver' => 'file'`, after the initial login, in the `app/storage/sessions` there is one file. And if i go from one subdomain to another, no other files are generated.
Though when i preform a CORS ajax, every time a new file is generated...

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same issue here.

Comment: Quick question, how you set up the domain of your cookies?

Comment: in the app/config/session.php file, set the 'domain' appropriately. (for a multi sub-domain site set it to ".site.com")

Comment: Same here! With Laravel 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your configuration, maybe you have the same problem that I had. I wasn't using Auth, but sessions and got `null` everytime. I solved it by changing this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
...
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

to this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000');
...
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

The reason that I found is that when you use the credentials it needs to specify the origin for security purposes, and for the AJAX request it needs to specify the credentials, too. I use Angular and I did this with `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials=true;`, but I really don't know the corresponding instruction for jQuery, but I hope you can find it.

Check the headers of the request and responses with your favourite debugger (Firebug for me). They should have a cookie attribute (it contains something with "laravel", "token", etc.) that the second time should be equal to the first response header.